# How to check a path of object properties are defined?

Tags: javascript

So, there's about a billion questions here on how to check if an object property in JavaScript is defined or not. They work great. Well, until I have a situation like this:

```js
var obj = {
    prop1: {
        prop1a: {
            prop1aa: "somestring"
        }
    }
};

//conditional stuff happens, potentially changing obj's structure

//Use your method of choice for checking if this is defined or not:
if (typeof obj.prop2.prop2a.prop2aa !== "undefined") {
    //prop2aa is defined, do something with it!
}
```

However, since prop2 itself isn't defined in some situations, this check throws an error in those situations. Is there a robust way to check if a distant property is defined in an object without resorting to a series of if checks at every single level of the object on the way to the desired property?

Comment: You have to check each one -> `if ( obj && obj.prop1 && obj.prop1.prop1a  )` etc

Comment: Awesome, didn't find that question at all in about two hours of searching. Thanks!